# Convert dateFromString to another format - SWIFT

Tags: swift

Sorry if this has been asked before.

I have a date from MySQL populating a tableview in Swift. I am converting the MySQL date to NSDate

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
let dateString = "\(dateLabelSource)"
if let dateAdded = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)
{
    self.dateLabel.text = "\(dateAdded)"
}
```

This produces the correct date but now I need to change the output to read more like:

```
Monday 7 September 2015
```

but can't work out how to do this.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should produce the output you want. Note: NSDateFormatters are expensive objects to create, so it is best to reuse a single instance as much as you can.

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
let dateString = "\(dateLabelSource)"
if let dateAdded = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)
{
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE d MMMM yyyy"
    self.dateLabel.text = "\(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(dateAdded))"
}
```

The Data Formatting Guide has a section dealing with formatting dates. [Data Formatting Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW4)

Answer (score 0):

This will Help

```
var formatter: NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "EEEE d MMMM yyyy"
let stringDate: String = formatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())
println(stringDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to format date:

```
let dateFmt: NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFmt.dateFormat = "EEEE d MMMM yyyy"
dateFmt.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US") // If you consider to not localise date
println(dateFmt.stringFromDate(dateAdded))
```